# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 c#

Tags: c#, mysql, excel

I am trying to load data from xls to mysql database, but, I am getting this error:

```
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

In this cycle, I am trying to select iteratively all values from 2-nd column of my excel and insert it into  db (excluding first row, because first row in xls is the name of my column). rowcount is 487.

```
   for (int x = 2; x < rowCount; x++)
        {

            string str = xlRange.Cells[x, 2].Text;

            string query = "INSERT INTO feture (F1) VALUES (" + str + ")";
            MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conect);
            cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        }
```

So where do I have problem? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String values have to be surrounded by single quotes `'`.

**Change**:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO feture (F1) VALUES (" + str + ")";
```

**To**:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO feture (F1) VALUES ( '" + str + "' )";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use *single quotes* with your value but more importantly, you should use *parameterized queries* instaed of string concatenation:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO feture (F1) VALUES (@value)";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conect);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", str);
cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

If you are wondering **why** do some research about `SQL Injection`.